# Autowire dependency in builder class with static instantiation method

Tags: java, spring, autowired, builder

I'm pondering this builder class that should calculate a hash from the field values. Maybe this in itself is wrong for starters, but at the moment it seems to me that it belongs there because I'm striving to an immutable `Article`.

I would like to autowire/inject `ArticleMD5HashCalculator` but when I put `@Autowired` on the field, IntelliJ complains: field injection is not recommended. Constructor injection is not possible because it's a builder pattern class, which means it has a private constructor without parameters and a static method for instantiation where it would be awkward to pass in hashCalculator.

The builder is injected into a scraper. The scraper will reuse the same builder for many articles. When Spring creates the builder with prototype scope, the builder will carry old values when the next article doesn't overwrite the old values.

New'ing the hashCalculator results is a hard dependency, making it impractical to inject mocks. What is the best way to handle this situation?

Here's the code of how it is now:

```
import org.observer.media.utils.ArticleMD5HashCalculator;
import org.observer.media.utils.MD5HashCalculator;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class ArticleBuilder {

    private ArticleMD5HashCalculator hashCalculator;

    private String headline;
    private String subheading;
    private String lead;
    // other article fields...

    private ArticleBuilder() {
        // This seems wrong.
        this.hashCalculator = new ArticleMD5HashCalculator(new MD5HashCalculator());
    }

    public static ArticleBuilder article() {
        return new ArticleBuilder();
    }

    public ArticleBuilder withHeadline(String headline) {
        this.headline = headline;
        return this;
    }

    //Other with-methods...

    public Article build() {
        // calculateHash() is called in the 9th argument.
        return new Article(headline, subheading, lead, body, images, quotations, subArticles, url, calculateHash(), author, sources, category, subjects, index, medium, company, datePublished, dateFetched);
    }

    private String calculateHash() {
        return hashCalculator.hash(headline, subheading, lead, body, quotations, datePublished, dateFetched);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. There is one to one relationship between ArticleBuilder and ArticleMD5HashCalculator. Meaning you don't plan to inject different instances of hashCalculator into ArticleBuilder at different places in the project (essentially having multiple instances of ArticleBuilder)

You can change the ArticleBuilder impl as follows

```
public class ArticleBuilder {

    private ArticleMD5HashCalculator hashCalculator;

    public ArticleBuilder(ArticleMD5HashCalculator hashCalculator) { 
        this.hashCalculator = hashCalculator;
    }
}
```

You can create a spring bean of type `ArticleMD5HashCalculator` and have this injected into a spring bean of type `ArticleBuilder` the following way.

```
@Configuration
public class ArticleConfig {

    @Bean
    public ArticleMD5HashCalculator articleMD5HashCalculator() {
        return new ArticleMD5HashCalculator(new MD5HashCalculator());
    }

    @Bean
    public ArticleBuilder() {
        return new ArticleBuilder(articleMD5HashCalculator());
    }
}
```

You can autowire `ArticleBuilder` elsewhere in your project and use it as a builder.

I am not sure why you made a private constructor and a static method to invoke that. I assume it is because you want a singleton ArticleBuilder. That can be achieved with the above approach. Correct me if I am wrong about this.

**Update 1:**

Based on the information you provided in the comments, you are injecting `ArticleBuilder` in a `Scraper` object and you want to have a way of getting a new instance of `ArticleBuilder` every time. You can use spring `@Lookup` annotation for that.

Stub implementation of `Scraper` class.

```
public class Scraper {


    //assuming this is the method where you want to use ArticleBuilder
    public void scrape() {
        getArticleBuilder();
    }

    //You can even pass constructor arguments to this method. 
    //They will be used to match a constructor on the target bean and that gets invoked
    @Lookup
    public ArticleBuilder getArticleBuilder() {
        //Spring creates a runtime implementation of this method.
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can call `getArticleBuilder` anytime you want a new instance of the bean. If it is declared prototype, you will always get a new instance of the bean.

But the only caveat with this is that Lookup annotation is not going to work with beans created with `@Bean` annotation. You alternate config may look like this.

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ArticleBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleMD5HashCalculator hashCalculator;

    public ArticleBuilder(ArticleMD5HashCalculator hashCalculator) { 
        this.hashCalculator = hashCalculator;
    }
}

@Component
public class ArticleMD5HashCalculator {

    public ArticleMD5HashCalculator(MD5HashCalculator hashCalculator) {
        this.hashCalculator = hashCalculator;
    }
}
```

beans.xml:

```
<beans>
    <bean class="MD5HashCalculator" /> 
    <!-- Fully qualified class name is needed -->
</beans>
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I think your ArticleBuilder is missing @Autowired annotation? The private constructor and static method is a default construct for implementing the builder pattern. ArticleBuilder should not be a singleton because then it could hold values of an article it had build before. But your answer put me on the right track.

Comment: You can make it a prototype bean in that case. I am creating the ArticleBuilder instance in Configuration class. It is similar to adding a bean entry in the xml. I think you meant missing Component annotation? You don't need to annotate the actual class with Component annotation in that case.

Comment: You're right, I meant @Component. I also thought about prototype when you mentioned singleton in your answer, but it poses a problem when reusing the ArticleBuilder bean. After processing one article, the builder has values. Normally you would again call the static method, resulting in a fresh object where all values are null. You could put a flush or clean method on the builder, but then it would be an awkward builder.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what the problem is. Can you elaborate? If you make the bean prototype, that also will give you a fresh instance every time.

Comment: That's because I haven't provided enough context. The builder is injected into a scraper. The scraper will reuse the same builder for many articles. The fields in the builder will have values from the first article, so if the second does not overwrite the old values, the old values will be present in the second article (when the build method is called).

Comment: Got it. So you are using ArticleBuilder elsewhere to create article objects and ArticleBuilder stores the state of the Article object as it builds it. With the static method implementation, you just call article() and you get a new implementation of the builder. So you don't have to worry about the ArticleBuilder having the old Article object's state partially. You want to have something similar using spring. Is that correct?

Comment: That's exactly the challenge :)

Comment: I have updated the answer based on what you have asked. Can you please update the question stating clearly what is it that you needed?

Comment: I tried @Lookup and it's working. I'll also post an alternative solution for other readers that pass by.

Comment: Sorry bud, I threw in some comment upvotes to make up :)

Answer (score 0):

Also due to convention used in Spring documentation please use constructor-based injection when possible.

> The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection as it enables one to implement application components as immutable objects and to ensure that required dependencies are not null.

Full info (scroll a little): [Spring DOCS](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-setter-injection)

Comment: I use constructor injection for all my beans but in this case it's not possible because this class is a builder (see builder pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I brewed up this alternative approach to pull out the `new`'ing and to open a window for injecting mocks. The solution implies that the builder has to be instantiated and recreated by a factory.

The factory:

```
import org.observer.media.hash.ArticleHashCalculator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Component
public class ArticleBuilderFactory {

    private ArticleHashCalculator articleHashCalculator;

    @Autowired
    public ArticleBuilderFactory(ArticleHashCalculator articleHashCalculator) {
        this.articleHashCalculator = articleHashCalculator;
    }

    public ArticleBuilder create() {
        return new ArticleBuilder(articleHashCalculator);
    }

    public class ArticleBuilder {

        private ArticleHashCalculator articleHashCalculator;

        private String headline;
        private String subheading;
        //...

        private ArticleBuilder(ArticleHashCalculator articleHashCalculator) {
            this.articleHashCalculator = articleHashCalculator;
        }

        public ArticleBuilderFactory.ArticleBuilder withIndex(int index) {
            this.index = index;
            return this;
        }

        public ArticleBuilderFactory.ArticleBuilder withHeadline(String headline) {
            this.headline = headline;
            return this;
        }
        //...

        public Article build() {
            return new Article(headline, subheading, lead, body, images, quotations, subArticles, url, calculateHash(), author, sources, category, subjects, index, medium, company, datePublished, dateFetched);
        }

        private String calculateHash() {
            return articleHashCalculator.hash(headline, subheading, lead, body, quotations, datePublished, dateFetched);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage of the factory:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.observer.media.hash.ArticleMD5HashCalculator;
import org.observer.media.hash.MD5HashCalculator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Java6Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        ArticleBuilderFactory.class,
        MD5HashCalculator.class,
        ArticleMD5HashCalculator.class
})
public class ArticleBuilderFactoryTest {

    private static final String HEADLINE = "headline";
    private static final String LEAD = "lead";
    private static final String BODY = "body";

    @Autowired
    private ArticleBuilderFactory articleBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private ArticleMD5HashCalculator hashCalculator;

    @Test
    public void build() {
        ArticleBuilderFactory.ArticleBuilder articleBuilder = articleBuilderFactory.create();
        Article article = articleBuilder
                .withHeadline(HEADLINE)
                .withLead(LEAD)
                .withBody(BODY)
                .build();

        assertThat(article.getHeadline()).isEqualTo(HEADLINE);
        assertThat(article.getLead()).isEqualTo(LEAD);
        assertThat(article.getBody()).isEqualTo(BODY);
        assertThat(article.getHash()).isEqualTo(hashCalculator.hash(HEADLINE, null, LEAD, BODY, null, null, null));
    }
}
```

ArticleMD5HashCalculator has @Component:

```
@Component
public class ArticleMD5HashCalculator {
}
```